# apache arrow - reading csv file

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

all 
I'm working with apache arrow now.

When reading csv file with arrow::csv::TableReader::Read function,
I want to read this file as a file with no header.

But, it reads csv file and treat first row as csv header(data field).
Is there any options to read csv file with no header?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `ParserOptions`

```cpp
int32_t arrow::csv::ParseOptions::header_rows = 1
```

It can be defined as third argument in `TableReader::Make(...)`.

```cpp
static Status   Make(MemoryPool *pool, std::shared_ptr< io::InputStream > input, const ReadOptions &, const ParseOptions &, const ConvertOptions &, std::shared_ptr< TableReader > *out)
```

Check the documentation: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/namespacearrow_1_1csv.html

and these test files:
https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/3cf8f355e1268dd8761b99719ab09cc20d372185/cpp/src/arrow/csv

Answer (score 0):

You can't at the moment. You'll got an error if header_rows == 0:

```cpp
if (parse_options_.header_rows == 0) {
    // TODO allow passing names and/or generate column numbers?
    return Status::Invalid("header_rows == 0 needs explicit column names");
}
```

(https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/3cf8f355e1268dd8761b99719ab09cc20d372185/cpp/src/arrow/csv/reader.cc)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a header, use

```
arrow::csv::ReadOptions::autogenerate_column_names = true;
```

They will name them f0....fN